# QGIS - Expression to aggregate values from an array

Tags: qgis, expression, array, aggregate

In a calculated field in `QGIS 3.10.2` I wan't to aggregate values from an array field. For this aggregation I'm using a filter to compare matching id's and return value from another field. I can aggregate values from a text or a numeric field, but I don't know how to reproduce this method with a list of values.

To be more precise:

- myTargetLayer: a reference table which contains id and text values

[image: target]

|  | idTargetLayer (integer) | myField |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | Grenache N |
| 2 | 2 | Cinsaut N |
| 3 | 3 | Carignan N |
| 4 | 4 | Viognier B |
| 5 | 5 | Chenin B |

- mySourceLayer: a layer which contains an array field of id's of target layer and a text field. In this text field I wan't to aggregate text values of the target layer (called 'myField' here). For example if array field is `'1,2,3'` I wan't to have `'Grenache N, Cinsault N, Carignan N'`.

[image: source]

|  | id | idTargetLayer (array) | Aggregate Field |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 9 | 4 | Viognier B |
| 2 | 8 | 1 |  |
| 3 | 7 | 1 | Grenache N |
| 4 | 6 | 2, 1 |  |
| 5 | 5 | 2, 1 |  |
| 6 | 4 | 1 | Grenache N |
| 7 | 5 | 1, 5 |  |
| 8 | 2 | 2, 1 | Cinsaut N |
| 9 | 19 | 2, 1 | Cinsaut N,Cinsaut N |
| 10 | 18 | 2, 1 | , |
| 11 | 17 | 2, 1 | 2,1 |
| 12 | 16 | 2, 1 |  |

**Simple aggregation**

```
aggregate(
layer:=layer_property('myTargetLayer','name'),
aggregate:='concatenate', 
expression:="myField",
filter:= attribute(@parent,'id_source_layer') = attribute($currentfeature,'id_target_layer')
)
```

If I try to iterate through each value of the array, it returns the same duplicated value.

```
array_to_string(
    array_foreach(attribute($currentfeature,'id_source_layer'),
        aggregate(
        layer:=layer_property('myTargetLayer','name'),
        aggregate:='concatenate', 
        expression:="myField",
        filter:= @element = attribute($currentfeature,'id_target_layer')
        )
    )
)
```

How to write an aggregate expression which iterates through each value of an array?

Comment: Can you add an example what `myField` contains?

Comment: Would be helpful to see the structure of your attribute table and see there what exactly you want to do - the description is a bit abstract

Comment: I edited my post to be more explicit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Note that if `"idTargetLayer"` in `mySourceLayer` already is an array, you need to remove `string_to_array()` for this field, [see comment by OP below](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/382803/qgis-expression-to-aggregate-values-from-an-array/382819#comment626667_382819).*

**Option 1 - Independent "ID", but more complex expression**

If your IDs are numerical but have nothing to do with the featureIDs of the layer, you can use this, a little more complex, expression:

```sql
array_to_string(
    array_foreach(
        array_foreach(
            array_foreach(
                string_to_array("idTargetLayer",', '),to_int(@element)), -- create an integer array of the values to search for
                    array_find(
                        array_foreach(
                            aggregate('myTargetLayer','array_agg',"idTargetLayer" || '|' ||"myField"), -- create an array of the IDs and myField values, intended to work similar to a Python-Dictionary, | is the unique separator between key and value
                        regexp_substr(@element,'[0-9]*')), -- extract the IDs of this 'Dictionary'
                    @element -- get the index of the value we will extract later
                    )
        ),
        array_get(
            array_foreach(
                aggregate('myTargetLayer','array_agg',"idTargetLayer" || '|' ||"myField"), -- create an array of the IDs and myField values, intended to work similar to a Python-Dictionary, | is the unique separator between key and value
            regexp_substr(@element,'[0-9][|](.*)')),  -- extract the Values of this 'Dictionary'
        @element) -- get the current integer array element of the value dict
    ),
',')
```

Its a little hard to explain, and even confusing myself, but I hope you get the idea of it. However, as the result shows, its working fine:

[image]

**Option 2 - "ID" is related to layers featureID and easier expression**

The following expression should work if the `id`'s of `myTargetLayer` are the layer's `featureID`'s:

```sql
array_to_string(
    array_foreach(
        array_foreach(
            string_to_array("idTargetLayer"), -- idTargetLayer is a string so we need to convert it to an array first
            to_int(@element)), -- idTargetLayer is a string field, so we need to convert the numbers to integer before we can look it up
    attributes(get_feature_by_id('myTargetLayer',@element))['myField'] -- get the attribute of ['myfield'] of the layer 'myTargetLayer' for the featureID '@element', where @element is the extracted integer of 'idTargetLayer' array
    )
,',') -- convert the gathered array back to a string
```

[image]

Comment: In both methods, expression dialog return an error message `Impossible to convert '[idTargetLayer]' to integer`, although it's an int field type. `MyTargetLayer` is a `PostgresSQL` table with a sequence who autoincrement id, could it be the source of the problem ?

Comment: @GeoGyro you can try replacing all `"idTargetLayer"` by `to_int("idTargetLayer")`

Comment: Same issue with `to_int("idTargetLayer")`.

Comment: @GeoGyro hard to tell then without your real data and structure. At least with your example as csv its working fine for me. Can you reproduce this issue with your example data? If not I can only suggest to debug the expression step by step then and double check your table content.

Comment: I'm agree with your suggestions. In your methods, `myTargetLayer` is a `CSV` and `mySourceLayer` is a `Shapefile` or a `PostgreSQL` table ?

Comment: @GeoGyro For testing I added both tables from your example as CSV. _(I guess thats also the reason why my feature id was +1...)_

Comment: I managed to replicate your solution with the same results using `CSV`. In my case it's a little different because I use `PostgreSQL/PostGIS` tables and an array datatype column, so I need to adapt your method 2 by not specifying `string_to_array` (it's already an array).